# "get_labels" method but for miniImageNet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, image-classification, imagenet

I am currently doing some practice on Few-shot learning tutorials and came across one which uses the Omniglot dataset.[This](https://github.com/sicara/easy-few-shot-learning/blob/master/notebooks/my_first_few_shot_classifier.ipynb). I wish to replicate it but using the miniImageNet dataset. This block of code is where I have been facing issues.

```
N_WAY = 5  
N_SHOT = 5  
N_QUERY = 10  
N_EVALUATION_TASKS = 100


test_set.get_labels = lambda: [
    instance[1] for instance in test_set._flat_character_images
]
test_sampler = TaskSampler(
    test_set, n_way=N_WAY, n_shot=N_SHOT, n_query=N_QUERY, n_tasks=N_EVALUATION_TASKS
)

test_loader = DataLoader(
    test_set,
    batch_sampler=test_sampler,
    num_workers=12,
    pin_memory=True,
    collate_fn=test_sampler.episodic_collate_fn,
)
```

What should I modify in this:

```
test_set.get_labels = lambda: [
        instance[1] for instance in test_set._flat_character_images
    ]
```

In order to allow it to run?

This is the error code:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-15761ef243cd> in <module>
      9 ]
     10 test_sampler = TaskSampler(
---> 11     test_set, n_way=N_WAY, n_shot=N_SHOT, n_query=N_QUERY, n_tasks=N_EVALUATION_TASKS
     12 )
     13 

D:\anaconda3\envs\FSL\lib\site-packages\easyfsl\samplers\task_sampler.py in __init__(self, dataset, n_way, n_shot, n_query, n_tasks)
     39 
     40         self.items_per_label = {}
---> 41         for item, label in enumerate(dataset.get_labels()):
     42             if label in self.items_per_label.keys():
     43                 self.items_per_label[label].append(item)

<ipython-input-7-15761ef243cd> in <lambda>()
      6 # The sampler needs a dataset with a "get_labels" method. Check the code if you have any doubt!
      7 test_set.get_labels = lambda: [
----> 8     instance[1] for instance in test_set._flat_images
      9 ]
     10 test_sampler = TaskSampler(

D:\anaconda3\envs\FSL\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py in __getattr__(self, attribute_name)
     81             return function
     82         else:
---> 83             raise AttributeError
     84 
     85     @classmethod

AttributeError:
```

Comment: Please always include full error messages and never edit or cut them.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy sorry, I made the edits and included the full code.